# Regex for accept the maximum one hyphen or space

Tags: java, regex

I have tried the below regex to validate the conditions as

```
Min length - 9
Max length - 10
Start with Numeric 
Ends with Alphabet
It allow one hyphen(-) or space -> this hyphen or space optional and either one only allow
```

the regex used is `^(\d)(?!\1+$)(?=.{8,9}$)[0-9A-Z]*(?:[\s-]?[0-9A-Z]+)*[\s-]?[A-Z]$`
it's working in most cases but it failed on the

7HND789-N or 7HND789N -> This is a valid one but it's not consider

The space of the hyphen before the last character is not accepting, its works in other places

Comment: What about `^(?=\d.{7,8}[A-Z]$)[\dA-Z]+[\s\-]?[\dA-Z]+$`

Comment: Beware the lenght of `7HND789N` is 8, so basing on your requirements it should not match.

Comment: Why do people always want to use a regular expression for such requirements? They always tend to be unreadable. Use simple `String` methods to assert the conditions.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose How can you verify if every character of a string is `[\dA-Z\s\-]` (that is kind of an implicit requirement) without iterating the string char by char (i.e. implementing yourself an automata)? I think in this case an acceptable solution would be to mix the two approaches, checking if the lenght of the string is 9 or 10 and if the string matches the pattern `^\d[\dA-Z]+[\s\-]?[\dA-Z]+[A-Z]$`.

Comment: How about [`^\d(?=.{7,8})[A-Z\d]*[- ]?[A-Z\d]*[A-Z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/wFVl7o/1) or with the same functionality this one: [`^\d(?!(?:[^- ]*[- ]){2})[-A-Z\d ]{6,7}[A-Z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/wFVl7o/2)

Comment: Oops, forgot the `$` in the first pattern: [`^\d(?=.{7,8}$)[A-Z\d]*[- ]?[A-Z\d]*[A-Z]$`](https://regex101.com/r/wFVl7o/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following Java regex:

```
^(?=.{9,10}$)(?=^[0-9])(?=[A-Z]$)([A-Z0-9]*[- ]?[A-Z0-9]*)$
```

Explanation:

```
^: Asserts the start of the string.

(?=.{9,10}$): Positive lookahead assertion. It checks that the length of the string is between 9 and 10 characters. The .{9,10} part matches any character (.) between 9 and 10 times, ensuring the string length constraint.

(?=^[0-9]): Positive lookahead assertion. It checks that the string starts with a digit. The ^[0-9] part matches a single digit at the start of the string.

(?=[A-Z]$): Positive lookahead assertion. It checks that the string ends with a capital letter. The ^[A-Z]$ part matches a single uppercase letter at the end of the string.

([A-Z0-9]*[- ]?[A-Z0-9]*): This part matches the middle section of the string, which consists of any combination of uppercase letters and digits, with an optional hyphen or space.
   [A-Z0-9]*: Matches any number of uppercase letters or digits.
   [- ]?: Matches an optional hyphen (-) or space character ( ).
   [A-Z0-9]*: Matches any number of uppercase letters or digits.

$: Asserts the end of the string.
```

Comment: its working but its allowing special chars and small letter , it should allow only Capital letters and numbers
6&D79K96N this should not accept
6aD79K96N this as well

Comment: The OP requires `7HND789N` to be matched by the expression, but here this is not happening.

Comment: @logi-kal the OP also stats that he wants a minimum of 9 and max of 10...so yeah its a little bit confusing

Comment: When is this going to match? `(?=[A-Z]$)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird this is to check that the string ends with a capital letter

Comment: @dan_pran Did you test it?

Comment: This is interesting, that you used the look-aheads to assert a length and, starting and ending characters.  I did not ever think of that.  Noted!